# Get right table data on LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a problem with my sql join request.
I need to get lines of left table who are not referenced in right table for ME (User 1) or referenced in right table with status equal to 0 and user equal to 1. 
I also need the field status of right table.

Here is my two tables :

```
Table left
ID | title
1  | Title 1
2  | Title 2
3  | Title 3
4  | Title 4
5  | Title 5
6  | Title 6

Table right
ID | status | user | left_id
1  |    0   |   1  |    1
2  |    0   |   50 |    1
3  |    1   |   1  |    2
4  |    0   |   50 |    2
5  |    0   |   1  |    3
6  |    1   |   50 |    3
7  |    0   |   50 |    4
8  |    1   |   50 |    5
```

My goal is to get this result :

```
left.ID | left.title | right.status | right.user
   1    |  Title 1   |      0       |      1 
   3    |  Title 3   |      0       |      1 
   4    |  Title 4   |     NULL     |    NULL
   5    |  Title 5   |     NULL     |    NULL
   6    |  Title 6   |     NULL     |    NULL
```

Here is my request for the moment :

```
SELECT l.id, l.title, r.user, r.status
FROM left as l
LEFT JOIN right as r ON l.id = r.left_id 
WHERE r.left_id IS NULL or (r.user = 1 AND r.status = 0)
```

With this request I get lines ID (left table) 1 / 3 / 6. But I also need the ID 4 / 5.
Those lines isn't displayed because another user (50) as a reference, but it's not me (1).

If someone can help me to add line 4 / 5 to my result I would be happy.

Thanks

Comment: But your Right table rows for ID 7-8, neither of two has user 1 and status 0 at the same row. So you will now be able to select these rows

Comment: I haven't any problems to get lines not referenced in right table, but for id  7 and 8 user 50 is linked to ID 4 AND 5 so my request didn't return them, I'm here to understand why.

Comment: You say "I need to get lines of left table who are not referenced in right table or referenced in right table with status equal to 0 for my user 1" but your left IDs 4, 5 are neither unreferenced in the right table nor referenced in the right table with status equal to 0 and user 1. Your expected output does not match your problem description. Do you simply need to get all results from the left table, and if it exists, the matching right record with status 0, user 1?

Comment: @hvd however, he misses the `Title 2` in the expected result ...

Comment: I think my description wasn't perfect to understand. I updated it so my need is : To get all lines (From left table) not referenced for me in right table and all lines (From left table) referenced in right table for me and status equal to 0

Comment: Just forgot to add `and r.user = 1` in LEFT JOIN. Thanks to @RadimBača. But no i don't missed `Title 2` in my results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small improvement of the query should be sufficient:

```
SELECT l.id, l.title, r.user, r.status
FROM left as l
LEFT JOIN right as r ON l.id = r.left_id and r.user = 1
WHERE r.left_id IS NULL or r.status = 0
```

Comment: I missed this try... Thanks I got the results I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
(Select t1.id, t1.title,t2.status,t2.user
from tableLeft t1
right outer join tableRight t2 on t2.left_id=t1.id
where t1.id not in
   (select tt2.left_id from tableRight tt2)
)

union

(select t1.id,t1.title,t2.status,t2.user
from tableLeft t1
left join tableRight t2 on t1.id=t2.left_id
where t2.status=0 and t2.user=1

)
```

Comment: A full outer join is preferable to a union as Postgres supports the former.